# How do I reload the menu?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Suppose I have menus displayed in my navigation, and suppose somewhere on the page I modify the global `$user` to some other user. Would it be possible to call some Drupal function to reload the Drupal menus that would correspond to that new $user rather than the already loaded menu for the old `$user`?

if so, what function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [menu_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/6).

> (Re)populate the database tables used by various menu functions.
>
> This function will clear and populate the {menu_router} table, add entries to {menu_links} for new router items, then remove stale items from {menu_links}. If called from [update.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/update.php/6) or [install.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/6), it will also schedule a call to itself on the first real page load from [menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_execute_active_handler/6), because the maintenance page environment is different and leaves stale data in the menu tables.